Over-driving and output comparison of XHP70.2s and XHP70.3 leds
Max lumens of xhp70.2s are rated at 4124 lm yet the Imalent MS32 flashlight outputs 6250 lm per xhp70.2 emitter (supposing net output of 200,000 lm). How are they able to do this with over-driving current? What would the max theoretical lumen output of a 70.2 be? As it's higher than the 'max lumens' stated by cree, what does 'max lumens' even mean?
Also, let's say that the 70.2s were replaced with 70.3s, rated at 5511 lm each. Would 32 of these using the same over-driving principle output more than 200,000 if they were pushed to their limits (more power supplied too), assuming that 70.2s already were?

lms is lumens abbreviated

Ok thank you. Do you have any answer to the question?

the difference in the measured output is caused by a difference in measurement procedure ... trust the manufacturer's datasheet, not an advertising agency's datasheet
